# Azure DevOps Release transform/replace tokens

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, xdt-transform

I have 2 config files, ConnectionStrings.config and ConnectionStrings.Release.config. These files are used  to store various connection strings we use in our app.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ConnectionStrings xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ConnectionStrings.xsd">
  <Service>
    <Name>MyService</Name>
    <Address>http://localhost/#{ConnectionString}#/MyServiceService.svc</Address>
    <ClassName>MyClass, MyClass</ClassName>
  </Service>
</ConnectionStrings>
```

When we deploy locally we use the normal ConnectionStrings.config without any replace tokens in the file. The .release.config is the one that has the tokens.

I'm using these 2 market place tasks
[Tasks in my release pipeline]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LP48.png)

From what I understand, the transform task is taking the .release.config file and "renaming it" .config, then the replace tokens task replaces the necessary tokens with variables in my pipeline. Finally I copy these to my target. My source of the copy task is my Git working directory in Azure.

When I check the results, I don't see the ConnectionStrings.config changed at all and its just copied over like if it was a local deploy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are the marketplace tasks you refer to configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using this extension: [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform). After installing it in my organization, there are 2 external tasks: [XDT tranform task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform) and [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) in release pipeline.

below is my repository structure, the ConnectionStrings.config and ConnectionStrings.Release.config.
[image][image]
And my release pipeline looks like below.
[image]
I create a pipeline variable `ConnectionStrings`, and set its value to `hello_world`, use the PowerShell script `gc _215\ConnectionStrings.config` to print the replaced result. Creating a new release we can see below log.
[image]
Thus it works as expected.